# jquery .load() loading whole page instead of an element. Is that right?

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

if I do this:

```
$('#myDiv').load('/somepage.aspx #someDiv #someOtherDiv', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

In the console I see the whole page code, instead of the contents of #someDiv #someOtherDiv.

Is that right?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it will load the whole page. If you want to load a particular section / div, try partial view (if you are on MVC)

Comment: MVC as in ASP.NET MVC 3, It allows you to create Partial views that you can call. But never mind, you got your answer.

Comment: Got you. Sorry, having a dim day today :) Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, thats right. jQuery loads the whole page, but gets only the requested elements (#someDiv #someOtherDiv in your case) from it.

Comment: Thanks. Thought I was going mad.

Comment: Because most web servers won't do partial page rendering (c.f. "UpdatePanel" in ASP.NET, it only displays the updated part but does a full page render under the hood to get that part).

Comment: I will. It wants me to wait 11 minutes before I can accept it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Of course,

jQuery can't ask the **Server** to extract that element from the whole HTML document. It loads the HTML document first, and on the client side, it performs a selection and returns that fragment.